# How to refer to Global name space in JS

Tags: javascript, namespaces, global

What is the variable for JS global namespace does it have a reference and can I change it?
(disclaimer yes I know that is terrible practice if I can)

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  However, in the browser, the global space is `window`. `window` and anything defined under it are directly available from any other scope in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser, it's accessible via `window`.

```
alert(window.document === document);    // true
```

I just tried to change it using assignment in Google Chrome, but surprisingly it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The global namespace/object for Javascript in a browser is `window`. As far as I know, you can change it, but don't.

**EDIT:** I was mistaken. Thankfully, you can't change it (e.g. `window = {};` has no effect, at least not in Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript that isn't running in ECMAScript 3.1 strict mode, you can refer to the global object using the keyword `this`, but only when not executing code inside a function that has an object context.

```
// In global scope:
alert(this.Math === Math);  //-> true

function test() {
    alert(this.Math === Math);
}

test();     //-> true

var someObj = {};
test.call(someObj); //-> false, `this` is `someObj`
```

In browsers, as other answers have mentioned, the `window` object is also the global object.

```
alert(this === window); //-> true
alert(this.alert === window.alert); //-> true
```

Answer (score 0):

The global namespace has these names:

`window` // most often seen

`top` // in some cases

`self`

`parent` // in some cases

`this` // in some cases